# Multidimensional Array in VueJS

Tags: arrays, vue.js

Creating an array with VueJS from a form input, processing and displaying a history of each processed input. It's a toaster processing different types of bread with different results.  Here are the requirements: 
    Make a toaster in `OOP`. It should be able to toast sourdough, wheat, and rye, 
    but it should reject white and English muffins. Also, it should never burn rye, but should have a random chance to burn sourdough and wheat. 
    Build a page to display in real time the results of each toaster use, 
    including a historical log of past usage (show 10+ random results). This 
    should be written in `VueJS`
It's not working.  Please see my codepen [VueJS Toaster Codepen](https://codepen.io/mountainocean9/pen/QBYzmz?editors=1111)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//VueJS Toaster

new Vue({
  el: 'app',
  data: {
    breadslices: data,
    breadtype: '',
    toaststatus: ''
  },
  methods: {
    toastSlice: function() {
      console.log(this.breadtype);
      if (this.breadtype == '') {
        alert("Enter rye, wheat, white, english muffin, or sour dough");
        return;
      }
      var toast = {
        breadtype: this.breadtype,
        toaststatus: this.toaststatus
      };
      if (this.breadtype === "english muffin" || this.breadtype === "white") {
        this.toaststatus = "rejected";
      }
      if (this.breadtype === "rye") {
        this.toaststatus = "toasted";
      } else if (this.breadtype === "sour dough" || this.breadtype === "wheat") {
        //Random Boolean >=.5 Burnt
        var randomburnt = Math.random() >= 0.5;
        if (randomburnt >= 0.5) {
          this.toaststatus = "burnt";
        } else {
          this.toaststatus = "toasted";
        }
      }
       this.breadslices.push(toast);
                this.breadtype = '';
                this.toaststatus= '';
      alert("The " + this.breadtype + " slice was " + this.toaststatus);
      this.breadtype = " ";
      this.toaststatus = " ";
    }
  }
});
</script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="toaster-slot-top">
      <input type=text v-model="breadtype" placeholder="ENTER  (rye, wheat, 
       white, english muffin or sour dough)">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" v-on:click="toastSlice">TOAST</button>
    <div class="title">
      <h1>TOASTER</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="toaster-history">
      <h2>TOASTER HISTORY</h2>
      <div> 
        <ul>
          <li v-for="(toast, index) in breadslices">
            {{toast.breadtype}} slice was {{toast.toaststatus}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please [edit] your question to clarify the part of your code you are having trouble with. Currently it is not clear what your question is. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Can you replace this line: if (this.breadtype == '') with if (this.breadtype == ='') and <li v-for="(toast, index) in breadslices"> with <li v-for="let (index, toast) of breadslices"> if it helps ill post it as solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation is almost there. I just reformatted some of your code to make it work.

I moved the

```
var toast = {
    breadtype: this.breadtype,
    toaststatus: this.toaststatus
  };
```

into just before the

```
this.breadslices.push(toast);
```

so that the latest changes to the `this.breadtype` and `this.toaststatus` will be added to the `history`.

Regarding the `breadslices: data`, I'm not sure what is the contents of that `data` variable so I just replaced it with an empty array to make the example work.

**Here's the full code:**

```js
//VueJS Toaster

/* Requirements:
Make a toaster in OOP. It should be able to toast sour dough, wheat and rye, but it should reject white and english muffins. Also, it should never burn rye, but should have a random chance to burn sour dough and wheat. 
Build a page to display in real time the results of each toaster use, including a historical log of past usage (show 10+ random results). This should be written in VueJS
*/
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    breadslices: [],
    breadtype: '',
    toaststatus: ''
  },
  methods: {
    toastSlice: function() {
      console.log(this.breadtype);
      if (this.breadtype == '') {
        alert("Enter rye, wheat, white, english muffin, or sour dough");
        return;
      }
      if (this.breadtype === "english muffin" || this.breadtype === "white") {
        this.toaststatus = "rejected";
      }
      if (this.breadtype === "rye") {
        this.toaststatus = "toasted";
      } else if (this.breadtype === "sour dough" || this.breadtype === "wheat") {
        //Random Boolean >=.5 Burnt
        var randomburnt = Math.random() >= 0.5;
        if (randomburnt >= 0.5) {
          this.toaststatus = "burnt";
        } else {
          this.toaststatus = "toasted";
        }
      }

      var toast = {
        breadtype: this.breadtype,
        toaststatus: this.toaststatus
      };
      this.breadslices.push(toast);
      alert("The " + toast.breadtype + " slice was " + toast.toaststatus);
      this.breadtype = "";
      this.toaststatus = "";
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  background: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/mountainocean9/image/upload/c_scale,w_600/v1534051512/samples/projects/toaster-306580_1280.png") no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5em 0;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.title h1 {
  font-family: Arial Black, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

.container p {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.toaster-slot-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 37px;
  left: 100px;
}

::placeholder {
  /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: red;
  opacity: 1;
  /* Firefox */
}

::placeholder:hover {
  /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  /* Firefox */
}

.toaster-slot-top input {
  width: 380px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #434746;
  color: #fff;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 563px;
  background: #000;
  width: 58px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: red;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
}

button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  width: 58px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.toaster-history {
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  left: 900px;
  top: 70px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #d3d7cf;
  color: #000;
  border: solid 5px #000;
  padding-left: 20px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="toaster-slot-top">
      <input type=text v-model="breadtype" placeholder="ENTER  (rye, wheat, white, english muffin or sour dough)">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" v-on:click="toastSlice">TOAST</button>
    <div class="title">
      <h1>TOASTER</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="toaster-history">
      <h2>TOASTER HISTORY</h2>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="(toast, index) in breadslices">
            {{toast.breadtype}} slice was {{toast.toaststatus}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here's a JS Fiddle:**
(Your codepen doesn't work so I transferred it to JSFiddle)

https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/264993/

Comment: Sure, No problem :)